# Approximating Bipartite Vertex Cover

Tags: graph-theory, approximation

Is there any result on approximating a minimum (weighted) bipartite vertex cover? I'm interested in the problem that given a bipartite graph ( probably with weight on its vertex ), find a vertex cover of size (or weight) at most ($1+\epsilon$) of the optimal value. I've been searching on internet and although it seems the problem was quite simple, there's no paper or lecture notes about it. (maybe because everybody know :)).

Can anyone give a link to related work if you know any :D

thanks

Comment: There are quasi-linear time approximation schemes for computing $(1-\epsilon)$-approximate matching, e.g. http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~pettie/papers/ApproxMWM.pdf

Comment: That's a great paper and it was exactly where I came up with the question.

Answer (score 8):

No need to approximate, we can determine the exact value: see [Kőnig's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_%28graph_theory%29). In particular, this [section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_%28graph_theory%29#Algorithm) shows how to use any maximum bipartite matching algorithm to find a minimum vertex cover.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm just interested in how to find a Vertex Cover WITHOUT finding a maximum matching, and get a better running time than bipartite matching algorithm.

Comment: I think these problems are well known to be equivalent - anyhow, good luck with improving the algorithm!

Comment: There are many descriptions of weighted matching algorithms, see e.g.
http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~wayne/kleinberg-tardos/07AssignmentProblem-2x2.pdf
The runningtime is n^3, but can be improved for sparse graphs
You should change the problem statement to ask for O(n^2) approximation algorithms.